# Method is not returning int

Tags: java, methods, int, return

I have this method:

```
int totalNumGrades(){
    numTotal= numA+numB+numC+numD+numF;
    System.out.print("Total number of grades: ");
    return numTotal;
}
```

and all the variables are initialized like this:

```
private int numA, numB, numC, numD, numF, numTotal;
```

so lets say:

```
numA=3, numB=3, numC=2, numD=1, numF=1
```

therefore numTotal must equal 10. Here's the problem, when I run the code all I get in the output is:

```
Total number of grades:
```

and that's it, the numTotal doesn't show up. If I put numTotal inside the print statement, it comes out as 10 like it is supposed to, but for some reason when I try to return numTotal nothing shows up. I couldn't find a solution online so please help. What did I do wrong?

***EDIT***

Thanks for all the answers, that was quick, and excuse my lack of knowledge on this subject, I didn't know you could put methods inside a print statement. Learn something new everyday. Gracias amigos!

Comment: I guess it is because you didn't write code to print what you want to print. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `return` does not inherently print anything.  If you write code that takes the returned value and prints it, then it will be printed.

Comment: LMAO - I'm sorry..just too funny.

Comment: Seriously, someone upvoted this question?

Comment: @childofsoong SO works in mysterious ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return numTotal;` doesn't print anything. It just returns 10 to the place where the method was called from. Instead, change the code that called the method to

```
System.out.printf("Total number of grades: %d", totalNumGrades());
```

Then remove the print statement that is inside the method. It's best practice to not print things from inside methods unless that is the purpose of the method as described by the method name.

Also, don't store `numTotal` class-wide if you don't plan on using it class-wide.
Just do `return numA+numB+numC+numD+numF;`

Comment: Just so you know, `System.out.print("Total number of grades: " + totalNumGrades());` would do exactly the same thing as the `printf` statement does here. I just prefer `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
System.out.print("Total number of grades: ");
```

to

```
System.out.print("Total number of grades: " + numTotal);
```

Also, you can write similar print statement in caller method to print the return value.

Comment: This won't be what @ioaop want because he/she says "If I put numTotal inside the print statement, it comes out as 10 like it is supposed to"

Comment: I answered this question of OP : 'when I run the code all I get in the output is:

Total number of grades: 

and that's it, the numTotal doesn't show up.' I have also added info to print the number in caller method.

Answer (score 1):

To print something in Java you have to put it "inside a print statement" as you said.

There's no way to magically print values without passing them to `print` or `println` or equivalent.

Comment: You can also use `write()` or other methods to print something, but this is not magic.

Answer (score 0):

Call method `totalNumGrades()` from main method
ex:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.print(totalNumGrades());
}
```

OR

you can use in same method like

```
System.out.print("Total number of grades: " + numTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not invoke the function you defined properly,this key word "return" just gives you the result,it will not print what it returns.
flowing will work well:

```
System.out.print("Total number of grades: " + numTotal);
```

The string "Total number of grades:" has been show up,only because you invoked the function "System.out.print(...)".

hope this can help you.